# position of element off by one pixel for top and left, in Firefox , correct in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, position

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="over" style="background-color:yellow;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
    <tr>
      <td>xxxxxxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>yyyyyyy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="t1">
    <tr>
      <th>head1</th>
      <th>head</th>
      <th>head</th>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>aaaaaaa</td>
          <td>bbbbbbbbb</td>
          <td>ccccccc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>aaaaaaa</td>
          <td>bbbbbbbbb</td>
          <td>ccccccc</td>
        </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
    tab = document.getElementById('t1');
    rect = tab.rows[1].getBoundingClientRect();
    over = document.getElementById('over');
    over.style.left = rect.left + 'px';
    over.style.top = rect.top + 'px';
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to overlay part of a table *t1*, with another table, *overlay*,by positioning the overlay table using the absolute position of top/left of the first row, in table t1. 
The given position of the first row form t1 is correct in Chrome, but off by +1
in Firefox for top/left.

Firefox gives this

[image]

Chrome this:

[image]

If you run the above code you will see the offset in Firefox and Edge.
In Chrom, Opera and Brave you will not see the offset.
This is annoying as I need exact positions for what I want to achieve.

Any Ideas ?

Regards

Comment: Your example has syntax errors. Please make sure that it is a [mcve].

Comment: I cannot replicate your screenshots. Both Chrome 75 and Firefox 67 show the same thing and neither look like the screenshots.

Comment: Non of my consoles in firefox 67.0.1 (64-Bit) nor in Chrome  Version 74.0.3729.169 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit) show any errors

Comment: I see this effect at work and at  home

Comment: Can you convert your code example into a Stack snippet? https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Snippet now vailable

Comment: What if you close the first `tr` in table `t1`? That's the syntax error I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I have entered a defect against Firefox

[Bug **1559098**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1559098)

The defect is meanwhile *'confirmed'*.

Regards

Heinz